# Is there a way to react to a parent hover without knowing the parent's classname?

Tags: css, styled-components

This is in styled-components, but I think the question works fine as a simple css question.

Is there some way to add a style when the parent is hovered? I've seen the question before, but usually expecting you have the parent's class. Is there a way to do this without knowing anything about the parent in plain css? Is there such a way in styled components?

So given

```
<div>
  <span class="inner">Hello world</span>
<div>
```

I want css like

```
.inner {
  :parent:hover {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Where 'parent' is trying to reference an element with no known class.

Comment: please add more details so that we know what is exactly your problem .

Comment: In short, yes... _but_.
You can create a more general selector and you don't necessarily need the parent's classname, but  you risk creating an inefficient selector that could break in the future or even include wrong elements. This requires a carefully built selector.

Comment: @Gil can you give an example?

Comment: Looking at your example, `div:hover > .inner` will work, but it's too broad. It's better to add another indicator of the div's parent in order to make it more specific.

Comment: Sounds like I'll just use the styled components approach to embed the classname of the parent for use in the child; was hoping this was doable, but alas

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to make a definite specific selection so it will depend on the rest of the styling as to whether you can be specific enough.

There are a couple of ways of trying to be as specific as possible given the structure:

```
<div>
  <span class="inner">Hello world</span>
<div>
```

Which to use depends on which part of the structure you are most confident defines the element you want to target - the class or the position.

```
div:hover > span.inner
```

OR

```
div:hover > span:nth-of-type(1)
```

Combining both might be what you want (I'm not sure from the question), but this is not currently possible with CSS i.e. `span.inner:nth-of-type(1)` does not select the first of the spans with class inner.

Answer (score 0):

Result here is there isn't a way to do what I described. The solution I ended on is:

```
const Container = styled.div``

const Inner = style.div`
  ${Container}:hover & {
      max-width: 200px;
      transition: max-width .2s ease-in-out;
  }  
`
```

This and the other solutions are all variations of 'use knowledge of the parent to get access to it' either via class name, knowing the element type or placement, etc. None of these are wrong, but unfortunately the more general styling of 'if my parent is hovered, no matter what that parent is, do something' doesn't seem currently possible